# Why does htttp.get give me an Error in Flutter

Tags: python, flutter, http, http-get

im trying to get A Value from a Python Script which looks like that:

```
    from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET'])
def index():
    return jsonify({"greetings" : "Hi this is Python"})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

After launichg im getting the following Output:

```
    C:\Users\finn1\PycharmProjects\FLASK_FLUTTER_APP\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/finn1/PycharmProjects/FLASK_FLUTTER_APP/main.py
 * Serving Flask app "main" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: ***-***-***
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Thei i imported the http libary in Flutter like that :

```
import 'package:http/http.dart';
```

Then i tried to get the Data with "http.get":

```
child: IconButton(
                icon: new Icon(
                  Icons.settings,
                ),
                onPressed: () async {

                  final response = await http.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/");
```

But i am getting the following Error when launching my App:

```
    Error: The getter 'http' isn't defined for the class '_HomepageState'.
 - '_HomepageState' is from 'package:what_todo/screens/homepage.dart' ('lib/screens/homepage.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'http'.
                      final response = await http.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/");
```

Thank You for Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;`

[package example](https://pub.dev/packages/http/example)

Comment: More explanation, you try to call `get` from `http package`, but you attempt to use `http.get`. so you need to specify an import prefix in order to seek the function from the import, like `import *** as http;`